# Pacman game in C language

Tags: c, pacman

I need to implement a 2-player pacman in C. The game will accept users apart from the two playing, however in view-only mode. Then they are admitted to the game in FIFO fashion.

I'm not so sure about which approach to take. I'll be definitely using the ncurses library to deal with the graphical aspect of the game. However I'm not sure about which IPC structure to use. Excluding the socket API, what do you think would be best and most straightforward way to deal with this problem?

Comment: While C is a nice language, I agree with SpyrosP. For a simple game like that a scripting language like Python is much easier unless you do it for the sake of learning C or it's an assignment where you cannot choose the programming language.

Comment: no in fact it is a requirement to use C. I just need to weigh up the different options I have, mainly which IPC structure to use and any design recommendations.

Comment: where does that requirement come from?

Comment: does it make any difference??

Comment: yes, if it's homework your supposed to say so or tag your question accordingly. Also explain why you're excluding sockets, that's a real common IPC mechanism, especially if the players are on different hosts.

Comment: aa sorry I didn't know that honestly. yes it is homework, that is why the requirement is to use the C language and not making use of the socket API. I didn't mention that is was just for the reason that I didn't ask for code (and will never do so), just an opinion from more experienced developers. what do you think is the best way to approach this problem? i.e. what IPC structure do you think is most suited?

Answer (score 2):

Excluding the socket API, including only the low level APIs, I would use named pipes to get the job done quickest.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more complicated to think of this as an *only* two player game.

Easier to think in terms of a generalized client-server arrangement, with any number of players.

Have a server holding the game state, with clients connecting.  That arrangement is easily understood and worked with.

Having only two clients and each maintaining the game state while receiving updates from the other is awkward.

Either way, use sockets.  That way you get proper location independence.

Comment: what do you suggest apart from sockets? Because I'm not allowed to use sockets at any point in the implementation.....

Comment: I'm puzzled.  It's multiplayer - so you'll need a keyboard and display per player.  That means separete machines.  How can you not use sockets?  are you expected to play two people on one machine, sharing a keyboard, with two terminal windows open?

Comment: yes the game must be played on seperate machines. I'm puzzled as well, that's the reason I posted this question here :S :S